# How to set the UITableView pulling area?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

As you can see, this is a UITableView, when the user pull down, there is some white area appear, is this possible to limit the size of this area? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your iOS6 project has no problem and the iOS7 project has this problem , I think you are find this property : `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

This property is added by iOS7.

> automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets Specifies whether or not the view
>   controller should automatically adjust its scroll view insets.
>
> @property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
>   Discussion Default value is YES, which allows the view controller to
>   adjust its scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed
>   by the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar. Set to NO
>   if you want to manage scroll view inset adjustments yourself, such as
>   when there is more than one scroll view in the view hierarchy.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

I think you can add this :  `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in your `viewController class` to solve this problem

Comment: That’s not what that does. This same issue will appear on iOS 6.

Answer (score -1):

Your helper is [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pull) select->download -> research - > clone git -> pull your bug fix :D